# Replacing html with jquery ajax does not change hidden field value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery ajax request that replaces some parts of the html on success. Inside this html that is replaced there is a hidden field value. When I retrieve the html from the server, the hidden field value is still the same even though it should have changed. I tried adding another hidden field value for testing, and this value IS replaced with the new. I can't seem to wrap my head around why this is.
When I debug in Visual Studio the correct thing happens: it goes through the 'else', not the 'if'. As you can see in this picture. It breaks on the else and the values should be 0. But when I debug in chrome, it says the value is the same. This is really weird! Why is the test variable getting it's value changed, but not the actual variable I'm trying to use? This is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Partial view that is being returned:

[image]

Html response when debug in chrome:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add `dataType: "html"`, while making AJAX call

Comment: I actually did that first, but tried to remove it to see if it had any effect. So, yeah, that doesn't work either.

Comment: #timeactivities-selector is already present, can you please verify this once? And try removing any hidden class, the Id should be available as non hidden field